# Why does this odd glitch exist with graphing programs?

Tags: graphing-functions, math-software

In Grapher on Mac and the TI-84's built-in graphing program, there is a problem with imaginary numbers. If I input $ i\sqrt {x}$, the graph ends up looking like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPm1G.png), even though it ought to look like $-\sqrt {-x}$. The same problem happens in the TI-84. I decided to test it in Grapher and entered
$$
y = \begin{cases}
  1, & i = \sqrt{-1}, \\
  2, & i ≠ \sqrt{-1}
\end{cases}$$
And it showed y=2. I'm not sure if these are the same bug, but I think they are related. I'm also not sure if the latter bug exists on TI-84. Note: This glitch doesn't seem to occur in Wolfram Alpha
EDIT: TI-84's normal calculation does just fine with this stuff, and so does TI-BASIC

Comment: Makes me wonder hat is the output of $\sqrt{-1}$ and of $i^2$.

Comment: @Kaster: I suspect the OP is thinking about real $x < 0$

Comment: @Henry, ha, I stand corrected. Mathematica shows it just fine.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The output of $\sqrt{-1}$ is still nothing, but the output of $i^2$ is different between the programs. In Grapher, it works just fine and shows -1. On the TI-84, however, it shows nothing.